# C# Selenium Proxy Authentication with Chrome Driver in windows forms

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want this code work in windows forms c#

```
var options = new ChromeOptions {AcceptInsecureCertificates = true};
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.Proxy = new Proxy {HttpProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", SslProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", Kind = ProxyKind.Manual};
//options.AddArguments($"--proxy-server=http://1.1.1.1:12345");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
{
    UriMatcher = d => true, //d.Host.Contains("your-host.com")
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("proxy_user", "proxy_pass")
};

var networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

networkInterceptor.StopMonitoring();
driver.Quit();
```

it tried to run it or async it its still not working